# How can I distinguish a pointer from a dereference in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference

```
int value =5;
void testPointer( int* pa, int* pb) {

*pa = *pb +5;
*pb = value;
value += 10;
}
```

How can I distingush both from each other? I dont get it

Comment: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/

Answer (score 8):

A unary `*` always indicates a dereference.

This may feel familiar and intuitive in an expression: `*pb + 5` means to get the value `pb` points to and add five. In contrast, you may find a declaration less intuitive; what does `*` mean in `int *pa`?

The way to think of this is that a declaration gives a picture of how something will be used. The declaration `int *pb` says `*pb` will be used as an `int`. In other words, when we get the value `pb` points to, it is an `int`. The `*` in a declaration represents the same thing that happens in an expression: dereferencing the pointer.

Kernighan and Ritchie tell us this in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90:

> The declaration of the pointer `px` is new.
>
> `int *px;`
>
> is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination `*px` is an `int`, that is, if `px` occurs in the context `*px`, it is equivalent to a variable of the type `int`. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear.

As a more involved example, consider `int (*p)[];`. This tells us that `(*p)[]` is an `int`. Since `[]` is used to access array elements, this means `(*p)` must be an array of `int`. And that means `p` must be a pointer to an array of of `int`. Just like `*`, `[]` does not have a reversed meaning in declarations. It does not mean “is an array of” instead of “access an element of”; it is still an image of how the thing will be used in an expression.

Answer (score 4):

When specifying a type, for example inside a declaration, the `*` means "pointer". Otherwise, the `*` means "dereference" or "multiplication" (depending on the context).

For example, when initializing a variable inside a declaration, all `*` before the `=` means "pointer", and all `*` after the `=` means "dereference" or "multiplication":

```
int i = 80;
int *p = &i; // In this case, * means "pointer"
int j = *p; // In this case, * means "dereference", so j gets the value 80
```