# Is there a logic behind the pointer operator conventions in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

`*` declares a pointer. I usually think "*int **pointer** a*" when writing `int *a`.

But then it gets confusing:

`int b = *a;` stands for "*int b is **value** of a*", not "*pointer of a*". And with `int *a = &b` the confusion then is perfect, as the new symbol `&` now stands for "***pointer** of b*" again.

Does anyone know the secret logic behind this convention? Why doesn't `*` simply stand for "*pointer*" and `&` for "*value*"? Or can these two symbols be thought as other words, so that it makes more sense?

---

EDIT: How this question is different from the four following questions that have been linked as possible duplicates, highlighting the difference between the associated questions and mine

- [Why is the dereference operator (*) also used to declare a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685514) (6 answers)
- [Why use * notation to both define a pointer and dereference one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740236) (1 answer)
- [Why is the dereference operator used to declare pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802392) (4 answers)
- [Is the asterisk in the pointer declaration an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460095) (3 answers)

My question asks about

1. the intended logic behind the two symbols `*` and `&`
2. how the `*` and `&` symbols can be thought / spoken in words

the linked ones don't. In addition to that, neither of the answers to these questions mention the page 90 of the 1978 K&R, where it sates that the declaration of the pointer is intended as a mnemonic. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Shoot. Where's my [copy of K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)? They might cover this decision.

Comment: In an expression `x = *p`, `x` gets the value pointed to by `p`.  So think of `*` as the "contents of" operator.  And then in `int *p;`, the way to read it is, "the contents of `p`, that is, `*p`, will be an `int`.  That's why the form `int *p` is preferred over `int* p`.  (And then `&` is the "address of" operator, or "construct a pointer to".)

Comment: I think it's better to see `*` and `&` as operators, they do multiple functions depending on the situation. For example, `&` acts as a reference but also as a pointer-getter, and `*` acts as a value-from-pointer-getter and pointer-storage.

Comment: Just to add to your confusion: Asking for c++ in addition to c adds even more semantics to thd `&` symbol. I'd recommend you get one of those beginner tutorials or books mwhich explain all these meanings in different context in detail.

Comment: There is a difference between _declaring_ a pointer and _dereferencing_.

Comment: Declarations should be read inside out. Obviously `int a;` means `a` has type `int`, but `int *a;` means `*a` has type `int` (in other words `a` is a pointer to `int`). So the use of `*` in an expression and in a declaration is perfectly consistent. Things aren't so simple with `&`.

Comment: Useful ref: `int *a` --> [`a` as pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*a).

Comment: Related: [How to explain C pointers (declaration vs. unary operators) to a beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27484168/2402272)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic is this:

- Unary `*` always indicates dereferencing of a pointer.
- When an expression is evaluated, the unary `*` causes the pointer to be dereferenced.
- A declaration provides a “picture” of how an identifier will be used in expressions.<sup>1</sup> So unary `*` in a declaration tells us that dereferencing the identifier produces the declared type. (See more below.)

In contrast, the `=` has different meanings in a declaration and an expression:

- In a declaration, the `=` after a declarator introduces initialization for the object being declared. It applies to the specific object being declared, not to the whole “expression” that is pictured.
- In an expression, the `=` means to assign a new value to the object on the left.

So `int *a;` means “When `*a` appears in an expression, it is an `int`.” Therefore, it tells us that the type of `a` is a pointer to an `int`.

Some additional discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75126322/298225) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436836/298225).

> `int b = *a;` stands for "*int b is **value** of a*", not "*pointer of a*".

`int b = *a;` says “`b` is an `int`, and initialize `b` with the value of `*a`.”

Note that `*a` is not the value of `a`. It is what `a` points to.

> And with `int *a = &b` the confusion then is perfect, as the new symbol `&` now stands for "***pointer** of b*" again.

`int *a = &b` says “`*a` is an `int`, so the type of `a` is a pointer to an `int`, and initialize `a` with the address of `b`.”

This logic also helps understand declarations of multiple items.
Consider `int a, *b, c[3];`. This says “`a`, `*b`, and `c[i]` are each an `int`.” From this, we conclude type type of `a` is an `int`, the type of `b` is a pointer to an `int`, and the type of `c` is an array of `int`. (The “picture” logic is stretched by arrays, because the `3` in `c[3]` tells us the size of the array instead of showing an example use of `c`. So the analogy is not perfect.)

(This is also why writing `int *a` fits the C and C++ grammars more closely than `int* a` does; the formal grammars bind `*` with `a` before binding with `int`.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Kernighan and Ritchie tell us this in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90:

> The declaration of the pointer `px` is new.
>
> `int *px;`
>
> is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination `*px` is an `int`, that is, if `px` occurs in the context `*px`, it is equivalent to a variable of the type `int`. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear.

Comment: "So `int *a;` means *When `*a` appears in an expression, it is an `int`.* Therefore, it tells us that `a` is a pointer to an `int`." is a fallacious argument, at least in C++.  "`*a` is an `int`" does NOT imply that `a` is an `int*`.  `int *a;` specifically means that `a` has type `int*`, and not merely "`*a` is an `int`" and logical consequences of that statement.

Comment: (Yes, it's OP's fault for asking about two languages in one question, but if an answer only covers one it needs to clearly say that)

Comment: @BenVoigt Is your argument, then, that in C++, "`*a` is an `int`" merely implies that "`a` is of a type such that `operator*` yields an `int`"?

Comment: @SteveSummit That's correct.  That's true for a large number of types (and is a pretty useful template parameter constraint aka "concept")

Comment: @BenVoigt: The explanation is about the logic of declarations, which was created when C was created and was later inherited by C++. While the current existence of overloaded operators would preclude concluding that “The type of `*x` is `int`” implies “The type of `x` is pointer to `int`,” that was not true when the declaration grammar was created and therefore has no bearing on the logic involved in the original design.

Answer (score 4):

> I usually think "int pointer a" when writing `int *a`.

The right way to think of it — bear with me for a moment — is that when you write

```
int *ip;
```

you are saying that `*ip` will be an `int`.  From this it can be deduced that `ip` is a pointer to an `int`.

This is the "declaration mimics use" strategy.  In the declaration

```
int *ip;
```

we see that `*ip` will be an `int`, and in an expression later when we do something like

```
*ip = 42;
```

or

```
printf("%d\n", *ip);
```

we can see that `*ip` is acting like an `int` — the form `*ip` in the declaration mimics the form `*ip` when we later use it.

An important point is that when you declare variables in C, the syntax is *not*

```
type-name list-of-variables;    /* WRONG */
```

The actual syntax is

```
type-name list-of-declarators;
```

On the left there's the name of a type, and on the right there's a list of things that will have that type — but the "things" are *not* necessarily simple variable names!  In fact, there's a whole 'nother little programming language you can use while constructing the declarators.  As a mildly extreme example, if you say

```
int i, j, a[10], *ip, f();
```

you are saying that `i`, `j`, `a[]`, `*ip`, and `f()` will all have type `int` — which is another way of saying that `i` and `j` will be plain `int` variables, `a` will be an array of `int`, `ip` will be a pointer to `int`, and `f` will be a function returning `int`.

Now, going back to what you had said:

> `int b = *a;` stands for "int `b` is value of `a`", not "pointer of `a`"

If you think of `*` as meaning "contents of", the confusion should largely go away.  If you think of `*` as meaning "contents of", then the declaration

```
int *a;
```

is read as "the contents of `a` will be an `int`", and the initialization

```
int b = *a;
```

is read as "`b` gets the contents of `a`".

(But I'm not saying you have to think of it that way all the time.  When I see `int *a`, yes, I read it as "`a` is a pointer to an `int`".  The explanation here is of how the notation came about.  It can be confusing, but it's much less confusing if you understand where it came from and how it works.)

> And with `int *a = &b` the confusion then is perfect, as the new symbol `&` now stands for "pointer of `b`" again.

`&` doesn't just mean "pointer", it means "make a pointer to" or "take the address of".

But the form

```
int *a = &b;
```

is definitely confusing, because you are *not* providing an initial value for `*a` — you are in fact providing an initial value for the pointer `a` itself.  If you do it on two lines, you have

```
int *a;
a = &b;
```

You do *not* say

```
*a = &b;      /* WRONG */
```

When you're working with pointers in C, you always have to be careful to distinguish between *the pointer* and *what the pointer points to*.  When you say

```
a = &b;
```

you're making an assignment to *the pointer `a`*.  When you say

```
*a = 42;
```

you're making an assignment to *what the pointer `a` points to*.

And when you say

```
int *a = &b;
```

you are simultaneously declaring *the pointer*, and providing an initial value for *the pointer*.  (In that declaration you're not doing anything with *what the pointer points to*.)

Answer (score 0):

The `*` symbol is used in two ways regarding pointers.  The first is in a declaration such as the following:

```
int *a;
```

This declares `a` as a pointer to an `int`.  Another way of looking at it is that `*a` is declared as an `int`.  The latter makes more sense when multiple identifiers are declared:

```
int *a, b, *c;
```

Here, each of `*a`, `b`, and `*c` have type `int`.

The second use of `*` regarding pointers is in an expression.  In this case, `*` is the *dereference operator*.  It takes a pointer as its argument, and the resulting expression is what that pointer points to.

The above is related to `&` which is the *address-of operator*.  It takes an lvalue, i.e. a name or expression designating an object, and the result is the address of that object.

So when you see something like `*a`, you know that `a` is a pointer.